# Do not understand where these terms are from in a product of exponential random variable

Tags: probability

This example comes from Tsitsiklis' *Introduction to Probability*.

I don't really quite understand what the product and log are about.

1. I get that the exponential RV is $\theta e^{-\theta x}$. But then what is the $x_i$ in $\prod^n_{i=1}\theta e^{-\theta x_i}$?
2. Is the product (ie. $\prod$) essentially the same as $\theta e^{-\theta x_1} \times \theta e^{-\theta x_2} \times ...\theta e^{-\theta x_n}$? (But this makes those indexed $x$ more confusing...what's the difference between them and just $x$?)
3. Where does the $y_n$ come from in $n \log\theta-\theta y_n$?

I apologise for asking such elementary questions, but I am trying to learn probability with a limited maths background. Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The $x_i$ are the values associated with the $X_i$, i.e. the realisations of the RV $X_i$. A definition is given for the $X_i$ as the difference in arrival times of successive customers. Considering $n$ customers you have $n$ differences in arrival times, with special consideration for $X_1$.
2. Yes that is what $\prod$ represents, a product. $x$ is a general symbol for a value without regard to a particular observation, $x_i$ is the value of the $i^{th}$ observation.
3. log of a product is the sum of the logs, i.e.
   $$
   \log(AB)=\log A+\log B
   $$
   This extends to any number of terms in the product, in essence for the log-likelihood (ignoring one of the $\theta$ factors, which if included would generate the $n \log \theta$ term)
   $$
   \log \left( \prod_i^n \exp(-\theta x_i) \right) = \Sigma_i^n  \log(\exp(-\theta x_i))=\Sigma_i^n (-\theta x_i) = -\theta \, \Sigma_i^n x_i = -\theta y_n
   $$

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your patience with such elementary question, got it all cleared up now